# Find index of non zero number number along the axis in two dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

Solved the following question as asked below , this is brute force way to solve this problem. Anyone help me to get a better solution of it. Its require to return the index so I have used String as return type, here also in case of returning the index need some improvement.

```
public class FindNonNegativeAxisIndex {

    public static String getAxisIndex(int arr[][], int row, int col) {

        int rowCount = 0;
        int colCount = 0;
        if (row == 0 && col == 0)
            return null;

        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            rowCount = 0;
            colCount = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                if (arr[i][j] > 0) {

                    for (int k = 0; k < row; k++) {
                        if (arr[k][j] > 0)
                            rowCount++;

                    }

                    for (int l = 0; l < col; l++) {
                        if (arr[i][l] > 0)
                            colCount++;
                    }
                    if (rowCount == 1 && colCount == 1)
                        return i + " " + j;
                }
            }
        }

        return null;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int arr[][] = { { 0, 0, 3, 0 }, { 0, 1, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 2, 4 },
                { 5, 0, 0, 0 } };
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                System.out.print(arr[i][j] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        String value = getAxisIndex(arr, 4, 4);
        String index[] = value.split(" ");
        System.out.println("row " + index[0] + "  col " + index[1]);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing which comes in mind is to check every row only once. We are going along the row looking for non-null value. If we found such value exactly once, then we check the column as well, otherwise go to the next row. This way you have at most two nested loops.

Also note that there's no need to iterate the loop once we already found that current number is unsatisfactory. We can use `break` in such case. Finally you should not create a string, then split it. Better to return a custom object, but for simplicity it's ok to return a two-element `int[]` array. Here's the whole code:

```
public static int[] getAxisIndex(int arr[][], int row, int col) {
    if (row == 0 && col == 0)
        return null;

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        int nonNullCol = -1;
        for(int j=0; j<col; j++) {
            if(arr[i][j] != 0) {
                if(nonNullCol == -1) {
                    nonNullCol = j;
                } else {
                    nonNullCol = -1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(nonNullCol != -1) {
            for(int ii = 0; ii < row; ii++) {
                if(ii != i && arr[ii][nonNullCol] != 0) {
                    nonNullCol = -1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(nonNullCol != -1)
                return new int[] {i, nonNullCol};
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int arr[][] = { { 0, 0, 3, 0 }, { 0, 1, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 2, 4 },
            { 5, 0, 0, 0 } };
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i][j] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    int[] idx = getAxisIndex(arr, 4, 4);
    if(idx == null)
        System.out.println("Not found");
    else
        System.out.println("row " + idx[0] + "  col " + idx[1]);
}
```